# Cant Figure Out Why VideoDeviceInput Isn't Being Added To My AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Everything is working just fine. Outputs are added correctly, everything is initialized correctly, camera pops up, etc. The ONLY thing that is not working is adding the video device as an input to the capture session or this camera and I cannot gather why this is happening.

Maybe a different set of eyes can catch what is going on here. I would really appreciate it if someone can take a look please?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AVFoundation


class CameraViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var recordingImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var captureButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var flipCameraButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var switchCaptureButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!

    let cameraCapturePosition: AVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back
    let session: AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let totalTime: Float64 = 1800               // total time in seconds
    let preferredTimeScale: Int32 = 45          // 45 FPS
    let minFreeSpace: Int64 = 65999999         // minimum free disk space

    var dataObject: AnyObject?
    var cameraCaptureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
    var audioCaptureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
    var movieFileOutput: AVCaptureMovieFileOutput?
    var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var captureConnection: AVCaptureConnection?
    var weAreRecording: Bool = false
    var beenHereBefore: Bool = false
    var devicesSet: Bool = false

    //**************** VIEW DID LOAD *****************
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        registerRuntimeError()
        registerDeviceConnections()
        setSessionPreset()
    }

    //**************** VIEW DID APPEAR *****************
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        //------INITIALIZE THE CAMERA------
        if (!self.beenHereBefore) {
            addInputs()
            addOutputs()
            setCameraOutputProperties()
            startSession()
            self.beenHereBefore = true
        }
        else {
            println("Been Here Before")
        }

        self.weAreRecording = false
    }

    //**************** DID RECEIVE MEMORY WARNING *****************
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //**************** TAKES A PHOTO OR VIDEO *****************
    @IBAction func didPressCapture(sender: AnyObject) {


    }

    //**************** SWITCHES THE CAPTURE MODES OF THE CAMERA ****************
    @IBAction func didPressSwitchCapture(sender: AnyObject) {
//        
//        ----------- TODO ------------
//        
    }

    //**************** FLIPS THE CAMERA BACK AND FORTH ****************
    @IBAction func didPressFlipCamera(sender: AnyObject) {
//        
//        ----------- TODO ------------
//        
    }


    //**************** INITIALIZE THE VIDEO CAPTURE SESSION ****************
    func setSessionPreset() {

        println("initializing video capture session")

        //----- SET THE IMAGE QUALITY / RESOLUTION -----
        //Options:
        //  AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh - Highest recording quality (varies per device)
        //  AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium - Suitable for WiFi sharing (actual values may change)
        //  AVCaptureSessionPresetLow - Suitable for 3G sharing (actual values may change)
        //  AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 - 640x480 VGA (check its supported before setting it)
        //  AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 - 1280x720 720p HD (check its supported before setting it)
        //  AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto - Full photo resolution (not supported for video output)
        if session.canSetSessionPreset(AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh) {
            println("Capture Session preset is set to High Quality")
            session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
        }
        else {
            //------IF FAILED, SET DEFAULT PRESET TO MEDIUM------
            println("Capture Session preset is set to Medium Quality")
            session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium
        }
    }

    //**************** ADD CAPTURE SESSION INPUTS ****************
    func addInputs() {

        println("Getting array of available capture devices")

        //------GRAB ALL OF THE DEVICES------
        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

        //------FIND THE CAMERA MATCHING THE POSITION------
        for device in devices {
            if device.position == self.cameraCapturePosition {
                self.cameraCaptureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                println("Back camera has been added")
            }
        }

        var error1: NSError? = nil
        let videoDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.cameraCaptureDevice, error: &error1)

        //------PRINT ERROR IF ONE OCCURS------
        if error1 != nil {
            println("Error1 ---: \(error1?.description)")
        }

        //------ADD VIDEO AND AUDIO INPUT------
        println("Trying to add video input")
        if self.cameraCaptureDevice != nil {
            if self.session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) {
                self.session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
                println("Successfully added video input")
                self.devicesSet = true
            }
            else {
                // !!!!!!!!------- VIDEO INPUT IS NOT BEING ADDED TO THE SESSION -----------!!!!!!!!!!!
                println("Could not add video input")
            }
        }
        else {
            println("Could not create video device")
        }
    }

    //**************** ADD CAPTURE SESSION OUTPUTS ****************
    func addOutputs() {

        //------SET JPEG OUTPUT------
        println("Setting JPEG Output")
        self.stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        let outputSettings = [ AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG ]
        self.stillImageOutput!.outputSettings = outputSettings
        println("Successfully configured JPEG Ouput")

        //------SET MOVIE FILE OUPUT MAX DURATION------
        println("Setting Movie File Max Duration")
        self.movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
        let maxDuration:CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(self.totalTime, self.preferredTimeScale)
        self.movieFileOutput!.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration
        println("Successully set movie file max duration")
        println("Setting movie file minimun byte space")
        self.movieFileOutput!.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = self.minFreeSpace
        println("Successfully added minium free space")


        //------ADD JPEG OUTPUT AND MOVIE FILE OUTPUT TO SESSION OUTPUT------
        println("Adding still image and movie file output")
        if self.session.canAddOutput(self.stillImageOutput) && self.session.canAddOutput(self.movieFileOutput) {
            self.session.addOutput(self.stillImageOutput)
            self.session.addOutput(self.movieFileOutput)
            println("Successfully added still image and movie file outputs")
        }
        else {
            println("Could Not Add still image and movie file output")
        }
    }

    //***************** SET ANY CAMERA PROPERTIES HERE ****************
    func setCameraOutputProperties () {

        //------INIT CAPTURE CONNECTION------
        println("initializing the capture connection")
        self.captureConnection = self.movieFileOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        println("Capture Connection succesfully initialized")
    }

    //***************** REGISTER FOR RUNTIME NOTIFICATIONS ****************
    func registerRuntimeError() {

        println("Registering for runtime errors")
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("didHaveRuntimeError"), name: AVCaptureSessionRuntimeErrorNotification, object: self.session)
    }

    //**************** REGISTER FOR DEVICE CONNECTION NOTIFICATIONS *****************
    func registerDeviceConnections() {

        println("Registering for connection notifications")
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("deviceConnected"), name: AVCaptureDeviceWasConnectedNotification, object: self.session)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("deviceDisconnected"), name: AVCaptureDeviceWasDisconnectedNotification, object: self.session)
    }

    //**************** START THE CAPTURE SESSION ****************
    func startSession() {

        println("About to add session inputs...")
        addInputs()
        println("Start configuring the capture")

        //------CONFIG CAPTURE SESSION------
        if !session.running {

            println("Displaying camera in UI")

            //------DISPLAY CAMERA IN UI------
            self.videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session)
            println("Video Preview Layer set")
            self.cameraView.layer.addSublayer(self.videoPreviewLayer)
            println("Video Preview Layer Added as sublayer")
            self.videoPreviewLayer!.frame = self.cameraView.layer.frame
            println("Video Preview frame set")
            self.videoPreviewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            println("Camera successully can display")

            //------START CAMERA------
            self.session.startRunning()
            println("Capture Session initiated")
        }
        else {
            println("Session is already running, no need to start it again")
        }
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the

AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate

Did your errors print? :

```
println("Could not add video input")

println("Could not create video device")
```

Comment: I have figured that out already. Thank you very much for your answer though

Comment: But yes they did print

Comment: Oh always be sure to answer your own questions for the mega points :D